# -bash: phonegap: command not found (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, cordova, npm

I just installed phonegap and cordova using npm on my Macbook (Mac OS X Mountain Lion) using these commands on the command line.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Both Phonegap and cordova seemed to install fine, but when I tried:

```
myMac:~ user$ cordova
myMac:~ user$ phonegap
```

I got the messages:

```
-bash: cordova: command not found
-bash: phonegap: command not found
```

both were installed, why does the command not work.

Comment: Probably because your PATH doesn't include the directory where you installed them. Try running `sudo find / -name cordova 2> /dev/null` to find the directory and add that to your PATH

Comment: Thanks, I used that and got
/usr/local/etc/bin/phonegap (for phonegap)
and 
/usr/local/etc/bin/cordova (for cordova)

How do I add these to the PATH?

Comment: You do `export PATH=/usr/local/etc/bin:$PATH` for now, and then do that same command at the end of ~/.profile so that it happens every time you login.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is an old question, but I think that my answer will be helpful.

I got the same problem and solve by creating a symlink:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.0.0/bin/phonegap phonegap
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.0.0/bin/cordova cordova
```

Remember to change this path ***/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.0.0/bin/*** to yours installation folder.

[]s