# Node Error When Downloading Cordova/Ionic Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I have been trying to download cordova or ionic on my new MacBook Pro for the past 2 days but I keep getting this error: `npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.1","npm":"2.14.7"})` I have tried almost everything but I was wondering if anyone else was coming across this error or is there something new that I have not figured out yet? When I install cordova I use this terminal command: `sudo npm install -g cordova`

This is the stuff that comes after the error:

`/Users/user/.node/bin/cordova -> /Users/user/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@5.3.3 /Users/user/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.3.3 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, unorm@1.3.3, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, semver@4.3.6, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, xcode@0.8.0, glob@5.0.15, elementtree@0.1.6, npmconf@2.1.2, request@2.47.0, cordova-serve@0.1.3, tar@1.0.2, init-package-json@1.9.1, aliasify@1.8.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.13, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@4.1.1, npm@2.14.9)`

Comment: it's just a warning, it shouldn't and doesn't break the installation process. In your question you say you install cordova you use `npm uninstall` , maybe that's the issue if it wasn't a typo :P

Comment: Edited post, sorry I mean npm install. The problem I am having is that it only has that one warming yet it says "cordova command not found"

Comment: are you interrupting the installation process after you see the warning? like hitting CTRL+C or something like that? because there should be more feedback when the installation of cordova completes successfuly

Comment: Edited post with stuff that comes after the warning.

Comment: hmm the installation seems to finish properly, does `$ cordova -v` command do anything at all?

Comment: It then gives me: -bash: cordova: command not found

Comment: the installation did finish properly, but cordova hasn't been added to your $PATH for some reason that I'm not sure of. [See this question and its comments how you could do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352686/)